# How to take the highest value of primary key in a table

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am following wpf mvvm . Here i want to display the primary key value + 1. ie, when the code executing , if the table is empty,then display the value of primary key as 1. If the table have 1 row,then display 2 and so on. so work this type., How to take the highest value of primary key in a table in wpf mvvm.

Can i use Max function? then How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what You're trying to achieve because first you're talking about "highest value" in the table, and then the next you're talking something like "If the table have 1 row,then display 2".

Either way, in MVVM all the calculation linked to the Model is placed in the ViewModel.
If You want to show the highest "whatever-you-want-to-show" in a let's say - `TextBox`, You need to:

(In the ViewModel)

1. Create an `integer` that'll represent the maximum You want, let's say it's called **MyMaximum**. Bind to it in the View (to a `TextBox` for example)
2. Make the **Collection** You're binded to with your **Table** an `ObservableCollection`
3. Subscribe to `OnCollectionChanged` of the `ObservableCollection`
4. Every time `OnCollectionChanged` is being raised, you should recalculate **MyMaximum** the way you want to ( for example, iterating through the list looking for maximum).

Unless the data in your Table isn't from binding to ViewModel. You need to be precise.

If that's the case, then the calculation should be done on the **View** side. You need to create an Attached Behaviour if you're using MVVM and calculate it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. Let's assume you are using DataTable and the column name for your primary key is "ID":

```
private static int GetNextId(DataTable table)
{
    return table.Rows.Count > 0 ? table.AsEnumerable().Max(row => (int)row["ID"]) + 1 : 1;
}
```

If this is not suitable, please be more specific about what you need.